# How to update graphql endpoint (not using Graph.cool)

Tags: reactql

I spent some time working through the ReactQL starter kit and watched the intro video outlining how the kit is set up, but one area I am still confused on is where to put our graphql specific stuff if we don't use a Graph.cool endpoint.

Graph.cool seems great, but to get more experience with Graphql, I want to set up my own schema, queries, etc.

What is the best practice for handling our own graphql stuff? Do I place the:

```
app.get('/', {
graphiql: true
})
```

or Koa equivalent in the `config/project.js` APOLLO variable? I am more familiar with Express than Koa, but could also see it going in the `entry/server.js` file.

Answer (score 4):

The GraphQL endpoint is set in [config/project.js](https://github.com/reactql/kit/blob/master/config/project.js), under the `APOLLO` variable by default:

```
export const APOLLO = {
  uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cinomw2r1018601o42x5z69uc',
};
```

Change `APOLLO.uri` to point to another GraphQL server will update both the server and browser environments to use that new server.

If you want to create your own GraphQL server *alongside* the front-end web server that ReactQL starts by default, there's an example you can see here for wiring up your own schema and GraphQL endpoint:

https://github.com/reactql/examples/tree/master/graphql-server

(Usage instructions for example projects can be found [here](https://github.com/reactql/examples))

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks Lee!

Comment: Np @outward.up. Please upvote the answer, so it can help others.